# Oracle SQL Query to check valid date range for an activity?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called as `Activity` with columns like `activity_id` and `activity_date`.

Consider a data in activity table like below,

```
activity_id    activity_date    
1              1st June
2              1st July
3              1st August
4              1st September
5              1st October
```

Now I want to change the date of the activity 3, but I can not change the date to less than `1st July` or more than `1st September` as there are already some other activities on those dates.

The only valid dates for activity 3 are between `2nd July` to `30th August`.

Similarly, for activity 1, valid new date can be any date before `1st July`.

Similarly, for activity 5, valid new date ranges from `2nd September` to any date in future as its last activity.

**I need to give the validation message to the user in front end if the new date is not within the range.** 
Input to the query will be activity id and the new activity date.

Below is the DDL script

```
    CREATE TABLE "HEADCOUNT"."ACTIVITY" 
(   "ACTIVITY_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL, 
    "ACTIVITY_DATE" DATE
); 

Insert into "HEADCOUNT"."ACTIVITY" (ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_DATE) values (1,'01-06-2012');
Insert into "HEADCOUNT"."ACTIVITY" (ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_DATE) values (2,'01-07-2012');
Insert into "HEADCOUNT"."ACTIVITY" (ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_DATE) values (3,'01-08-2012');
Insert into "HEADCOUNT"."ACTIVITY" (ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_DATE) values (4,'01-09-2012');
Insert into "HEADCOUNT"."ACTIVITY" (ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_DATE) values (5,'01-10-2012');
```

Comment: How are you changing the date? It could be achieved through database triggers, or front end validation depending upon the method for changing the values.

Comment: @Ollie. I need to add validation at the front end.We are not using triggers. SQl query is used to update the activity to its new activity date.

Comment: your trouble is that validating SQL inserts is best done via triggers unless you are using some front end environment that can validate the inputs before they are sent to the database. Your other option (than triggers) is to update via a stored procedure that performs the validation before inserting the record and returns an error message if the validation fails.

Comment: @Ollie. I am thinking of using stored procedure but I am not sure what is the best possible way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find the date ranges for each row:

```
SELECT activity_id, activity_date
      ,NVL( LAG(activity_date) OVER(ORDER BY activity_id) 
           ,TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
          ) AS previous_date
      ,NVL( LEAD(activity_date) OVER(ORDER BY activity_id)
           ,TO_DATE('2100-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
          ) AS next_date
  FROM activity
  ORDER BY activity_id
```

Result:

```
                       ACTIVITY_ID ACTIVITY_DATE PREVIOUS_DATE NEXT_DATE
---------------------------------- ------------- ------------- ---------
                                 1 01-JUN-12     01-JAN-00     01-JUL-12 
                                 2 01-JUL-12     01-JUN-12     01-AUG-12 
                                 3 01-AUG-12     01-JUL-12     01-SEP-12 
                                 4 01-SEP-12     01-AUG-12     01-OCT-12 
                                 5 01-OCT-12     01-SEP-12     01-JAN-00
```

Validation would then be for a given id:

"input date" > previous_date AND "input date" < next_date

Date ranges are based on previous and following records when ordered by activity_id. Perhaps the ordering should really be by activity_date, though. Using LAG and LEAD will allow for gaps in activity_ids as well.

Answer (score 0):

Find date limits using a query like below (replace `@param_id` with changing activity id):

```
SELECT activity_id, activity_date
FROM   activity
WHERE  activity_id = @param_id-1
   OR  activity_id = @param_id+1
```

This query will return at most two results, but for first and last activities only one will be returned. So, you should read results in the front-end and decide what to do:

1. **Specify beginning limit:** Result with id `@param_id-1` specifies beginning date limit. If no result with this id, this is first activity and no limit for begin date.
2. **Specify ending limit:** Result with id `@param_id+1` specifies ending date limit. If no result with this id, this is last activity and no limit for end date.
3. **Do or warn**: If new date is within the range, perform change. Otherwise warn the user.